# How to calculate the space complexity in terms of recursion?

Tags: recursion, space-complexity

How to calculate the space complexity in terms of recursion? For example, is it equal to the maximum recursion stack at all points of program execution? or do (memory) released/returned recursive calls also count?
Thanks.

Comment: It's equal to the maximum space occupied at any instant. If you use X amount of space, then free it, then use X space again, then free it, then X again, etc, and do that Y times, it's still only O(X). But if you use X amount, then don't free it, then X again, still don't free anything, then X again, etc, and do that Y times, then suddenly you're using Ө(X Y) space.

Comment: So there would be a huge amount of difference in space complexity between these two functions: `function f(n) { use X amount of space; f(n-1); free space; }` and `function g(n) { use X amount of space; free space; g(n-1); }`

Comment: This similar question has a few longer answers: [What are the fundamentals of calculating space complexity in loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573130/what-are-the-fundamentals-of-calculating-space-complexity-in-loops)